# Ubuntu 12.04 how do I remove the guest option at login

Tags: 12.04, login

My first question is, how do I remove the guest option at login so it is just me who uses the computer/Ubuntu?

Comment: Hi Nick, can you split your question up into two questions and can you make the title of our question more informative?

Answer (score 0):

Remove guest login 
1.Go to your terminal by pressing ctrl+alt+T

2.Type the following command

```
    sudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

3.Enter your password and add  the folowoing line when gedit pops up

```
    allow-guest=false
```

4.Save and close the file

5.sudo restart lightdm

That should remove guest login option